# Particles update strangely

Tags: particles

When changing the settings of a particle texture (controlling density and size), the particle display in the viewport updates, but it does so in some weird ways.

Firstly, if I click on either of the color markers in the color ramp (if ramp is turned on), the particle distribution will change, even if I don't move either of the markers. Furthermore, the distribution is typically the same for a given marker. If I click from one to the other, the particles basically toggle between two distributions.

Similarly, if I drag the size slider in the influence section, the particles update, but they "flicker" between a fairly sparse distribution and a much more dense distribution as it updates.

What's causing this? Is it a bug, or am I doing something weird? I'll try to post a video soon.

EDIT:

Just to clarify what I'm doing:

1. Select each ramp marker (without changing them)
2. Click on black marker several times
3. Drag the size slider
4. Key 0.5 into the size field several times in a row

Changing almost any other setting on this panel will do the same thing. There are also several things OUTSIDE the texture panel that will do this.

[image: Particles change distribution when they shouldn't]

Comment: Could be the seed is updating . . ?

Comment: I don't think so. The seed for the particle system itself shouldn't ever change on its own. It should only ever change if the user sets a different seed. I'm about to add a video and I think it'll make a bit more sense.

Comment: particle day! it's really strange. but i'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: I'd like to object to the "off topic" based on the actual question: "Is it a bug, or am I doing something weird?" This is not a report, this is a question. I need to know if this is legitimate behavior.